# Getting Column Headers from multiple html 'tbody'

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-table

I need to get the column headers from the second tbody in this url.

http://bepi.mpob.gov.my/index.php/statistics/price/daily.html

Specifically, i would like to see "september, october"... etc.

I am getting the following error:

```
runfile('C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/xy/workspace/webscrape/mpob1.py', wdir='C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/xy/workspace/webscrape')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-ab4005f51fa3>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/xy/workspace/webscrape/mpob1.py', wdir='C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/xy/workspace/webscrape')

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/xy/workspace/webscrape/mpob1.py", line 26, in <module>
    soup.findAll('tbody', limit=2)[1].findAll('tr').findAll('th')]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

can anyone here please help me out? I shall be eternally grateful!

have posted my code below:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd



url = "http://bepi.mpob.gov.my/index.php/statistics/price/daily.html"



r = requests.get(url)



soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')


column_headers = [th.getText() for th in 
              soup.findAll('tbody', limit=2)[1].findAll('tr').findAll('th')]
```

Comment: Do you mean, you just need the contents of the month select element, or you actually need to click "View Price" and parse the "MPOB DAILY FFB REFERENCE PRICE SUMMARY BY REGION" table? Thanks

Comment: I need to click 'View Price'. The table in question that needs to be parsed is 'Peninsular Malaysia : Local Prices Summary of RBD P. Oil, RBD P.Olein & RBD P. Stearin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click "View Price" button a POST request is sent to the `http://bepi.mpob.gov.my/admin2/price_local_daily_view3.php` endpoint. Simulate this POST request and parse the resulting HTML:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get("http://bepi.mpob.gov.my/index.php/statistics/price/daily.html")

    response = session.post("http://bepi.mpob.gov.my/admin2/price_local_daily_view3.php", data={
        "tahun": "2016",
        "bulan": "9",
        "Submit2222": "View Price"
    })
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

    table = soup.find("table", id="hor-zebra")
    headers = [td.get_text() for td in table.find_all("tr")[2].find_all("td")]
    print(headers)
```

Prints the headers of the table:

```
[u'Tarikh', u'September', u'October', u'November', u'December', u'September', u'October', u'November', u'December', u'September', u'October', u'November', u'December']
```